# OpenCV calcHist raises intersenting error, how would I solve it?

Tags: python, arrays, opencv, numpy

Here is the line that raised the error:

```
 cv2.calcHist([patch],[0], fmasks[count], [num_hist_bins], [0,256])
```

patch is nxm numpy array
mask is nxm numpy array (in the same size)
num_hist_bins = 8
and both array are in the dtype of uint8

Here is the error:

```
OpenCV/opencv-2.4.10/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp:236: error: (-215) step[dims-1] == (size_t)CV_ELEM_SIZE(flags) in function create
```

Even I tried all dtype and data shape variations result is same with this error. Any suggestion for the solution ?